# Function differentiable on $(a,b)$ but not continuous on $ [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any function $f$ which is differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$ but is not continuous on (and also cannot be extended continuously to) the closed interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $x\in(0,1)$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: I have written the very same example...

Comment: @Anne You should tell us what attempts you have made to find a function like this

Comment: "not continuous on $[a,b]$" and "can't be extended continuously to $[a,b]$" are not the same things - which one did you mean? (the answers here seem to suppose the first meaning)

an example of the latter kind: $sin(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 35):

$$\Large\dot{}\!\!\underline{\qquad\qquad\qquad}\!\!\Large\dot{}$$

$$$$

Comment: What is it? Some sort of joke?

Comment: It is supposed to be a graph of such a function :)

Comment: ._.$\phantom{2}$

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x)=\frac1{(x-a)(x-b)},\qquad f(a)=f(b)=0.$$

Answer (score 4):

The easiest function I can think of is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt x&,\;\;x\in (0,1]\\{}\\18&,\;\;x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Timbuc How did you think of it *(I mean, rationale)*?

Comment: @pushpen.paul, the square root is my box example of function defined and continuous on a certain interval but not differentiable in one point there.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ at any interval $(n,n+1)$ with integer endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

[Differentiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) implies [continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), but the intervals $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ were *not* the same; the first was [open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) second was [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set). This means at the points $a$ and $b$ it can be not continuous and it will still be differentiable on open $a,b$.

Thusly you can have a function that does what you said.

---

For example, you could have $f(a) = 5$ and $f(x) =2$ otherwise (when $x \neq a$). This function will have a [discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) at $x=a$.